# Fetch each object from API data using vue and axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, render

This is my script that calls axios and fetch data as posts

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios'


export default {
  name: 'App',

  mounted: function () {
    axios.get('API URL')
      .then(response => this.posts = response.data)
  },


  data() {
      return {
        posts: null
      }
    },


};

</script>
```

My code on view that tries to fetch data as posts from the script above

```
<template>
  <div id="app"> 
    <ul>
      <li v-for="post in posts" v-text="post.createdAt"></li>
    </ul>
  <div>
</template>
```

SAMPLE data fetched from API URL look like this

[POSTS OBJECT VARIABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcOzC.png)

I am able to fetch API DATA in console log as an array but when I call one object from array which is createdAT, `v-text = "post.createdAt"` does not print/fetch list of createdAt date list.

Comment: There is no reason this wouldn't work, something else must be wrong. 
 https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/qjtbw7yp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved it following this document USING AXIOS TO CONSUME API here is the link for that https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html .

Above code that I have posted works fine. Problem was on my API URL which was nested inside data[data[object]]. So the way I called data from that API

from this

```
 mounted: function () {
    axios.get('API URL')
      .then(response => this.posts = response.data)
  }
```

to this

```
 mounted: function () {
    axios.get('API URL')
      .then(response => this.posts = response.data.data)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`posts` isn't reactive because the default value is `null`, make it an empty array, or use `Vue.set` instead:

Array:

```
posts: []
```

Vue.set:

```
.then(response => Vue.set(this, 'posts', response.data))
```

**Edit**

In response to the comments below:

You must `import Vue from 'vue'` to resolve the `Vue` is not defined error.

Regarding your `v-for-key` needing to be unique, you need to define a unique `key` on v-for elements. You can just use `JSON.stringify(post)`:

```
 <li v-for="post in posts" v-text="post.createdAt" :key="JSON.stringify(post)"></li>
```

Comment: When I used your suggestion , the error that i am getting now is

error  Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key
and
error  'Vue' is not defined

Comment: @sandeshphuyal I edited my answer to show why you have these problems. These are some fundamental concepts within Vue its self, so hopefully they're helpful.